# Skewness of a squared random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Say we have some probability density function $f(x)$ which is unimodal (with the modus at 0) and also symmetric in the y-axis. It seems to me that 'in most cases', the square of a r.v $x \sim f(x)$ would follow a distribution with a positive skew. If we take the normal distribution for example, we see that taking the square of $x \sim N(0,1)$ most frequently leads to values close to 0, but can also (less frequently) lead to large positive values, indicating a positively skewed distribution.

[image]

My question is the following: does the square of a r.v $x \sim f(x)$ always follow a distribution with a positive skew, and if so, how can this be shown? Alternatively, if this does not always hold, are there conditions that ensure this property does hold?

Comment: Depending on your specific definition of skewness (there are at least a couple that are commonly used), one can construct nontrivial counter-examples that are pathological. If you don't settle with a quantitative definition of skewness, then all one can is just handwaving talks.

Comment: I see. I'm not necessarily committed to any specific skewness measure, so I would have to balance both generality of the conditions (are the conditions for skewness very restrictive, or can a positive skewness be expected for typical cases), and simplicity (are the conditions easy to check/interpret). Since these properties might not be very obvious beforehand, I would go for the Pearson's moment coefficient of skewness.

Comment: With this in mind, if handwaving talks are still all one can do, then interesting counterexamples would also be appreciated!

Comment: You may think in the other way round. Let $X$ be a positive random variable, and $Y$ to be a mixture of $\sqrt{X}$ and $-\sqrt{X}$ with equal weight of $1/2$, so that it is symmetric about $0$. So you can see $X$ is quite arbitrary and can be either positively or negatively skewed.

Comment: @BGM I think the OP wants something that is "nice" in that the density of $Y = \sqrt{X}$ being "smooth" at zero (btw, unimodality is not possible for sure) and that density of $X$ doesn't vanish $f_X(t) > 0$ for any finite $t$.

Comment: @BGM, thanks for your example. However, I'm not sure this example would satisfy the typical definition of unimodality in the context of distributions. Shouldn't unimodal distributions have a single hill instead of a valley? This is at least implied by the name 'unimodal' which is derived from the modus, the most likely outcome. In any case, a unimodal hill is certainly what I meant, so I would even be more interested in a counterexample where the highest point is at $x = 0$!

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin, your additional assumptions make sense, especially given my example. But actually I require neither differentiability at zero nor a distribution that does not vanish. In fact, the distributions I am examing are all continuous and non-differentiable at $x=0$ and vanishing left from $x_{min}$ and right from $x_{max}$. Of course, by virtue of symmetry we have $|x_{min}| = x_{max}$.